# PyTorch/TensorFlow calculation of surface normal of a surface point cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, computational-geometry, point-clouds

Say we have a point cloud of a surface (np.array of shape=(N, 3)) like the below image, on which we want to define a trajectory.

[image]

So far using scipy.interpolate.griddata I can project the 2D defined trajectory and get the following:

[image]

but then calculating surface normal for each of these points is not quite easy.

Is there a way using PyTorch/TensorFlow to do something similar while using the automatic differentiation feature of them to calculate such surface normal easier for each point?

P.S. Although off-topic and better for a separate question: I am also interested if there is a way to define the trajectory on a local coordinate system on this surface and map it to the world 3D coordinate system.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You want to interpolate points on a 2D surface in a 3D space and get the surface normal vector at each interpolated point? I find the term "trajectory" quite confusing, because it normally refers to a 1D line and not to a 2D surface.

Comment: @JakobStark yea trajectory may be confusing. Let's say a simple grid of points on this surface that we want to get the surface normal at each point. Interpolation seems one possible solution for it that may help but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well I doubt, that automatic differentiation will help you much here. I would rather look into 3D graphics libraries to find algorithms that give you the normal vectors of a surface. After all your surface already consists of a finite number of points, so the differential naturally "decays" into the difference of neighboured points.

Comment: You could for example use Newells' method (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal) which essentially calculates the weighted mean of the cross products of the edges of a polygon in 3D. So you can take all the squares in your interpolation and calculate the normal vector for each of these.